# R List to one column in dataframe

Tags: r, list, transpose

my list looks like this

```
Volumen(Ist)  800 200 300 200_2 200_3 82.0 100 .....
```

And I need it like this:

```
Volumen(Ist)
800
200
...
```

Here some information about my code

```
> typeof(p1_daily)
[1] "list"
> p1_daily <- t(p1_daily)
[1] "logical"
> length(p1_daily)
[1] 0
> colnames(p1_daily)
NULL
> rownames(x)
[1] "Volumen (Ist)"      "0"                  "69.000000000000028" "72"                 "76"                 "79"               # .............. and so on
```

I don't understand what is happening. I just want to have this list as a dataframe with one column. That's all.

Thanks!

EDIT:

[Requested commands](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LlIkY.png)

Comment: `data.frame(unlist(p1_daily));`

Comment: [1] unlist.p1_daily.
<0 Zeilen> (oder row.names mit Länge 0)

Comment: I think you have a copy-paste error in your "information", how could an attribution return "logical" ?

Comment: please `dput()` your list or part of it if it is too long...

Comment: `typeof` isn't a very good diagnostic tool for this sort of thing. `typeof(data.frame(x = 1))` gives `list`, `typeof(matrix(1:4))` gives `integer`... please use `dput()` to share your object, or at least `str()` to see its structure.

Comment: I added them to the post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

would something like this be helpfull?

```
p1_daily <- list(`Volumen(Ist)` = cars[1:12,2])
p1_daily
#> $`Volumen(Ist)`
#>  [1]  2 10  4 22 16 10 18 26 34 17 28 14
class(p1_daily)
#> [1] "list"
foo <- data.frame(`Volumen(Ist)` = unlist(p1_daily, use.names = FALSE) )
class(foo)
#> [1] "data.frame"
foo
#>    Volumen.Ist.
#> 1             2
#> 2            10
#> 3             4
#> 4            22
#> 5            16
#> 6            10
#> 7            18
#> 8            26
#> 9            34
#> 10           17
#> 11           28
#> 12           14
```

If you really want the column name to be `Volumen(Ist)`

```
# install.packages(c("tidyverse"), dependencies = TRUE)
library(tibble)
bar <- tibble(`Volumen(Ist)` = unlist(p1_daily, use.names = FALSE))
bar

#> # A tibble: 12 x 
#>    `Volumen(Ist)`
#>             <dbl>
#>  1              2
#>  2             10
#>  3              4
#>  4             22
#>  5             16
#>  6             10
#>  7             18
#>  8             26
#>  9             34
#> 10             17
#> 11             28
#> 12             14
```